# Normal modes of a circular array of interacting particles

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, spring, coupled-oscillators, normal-modes

I want to study the normal modes of an array of $N$ identical atoms placed in a circular lattice. The particles interact among them via Yukawa interaction potential,
$$\phi_Y(r)=\frac{A}{r}exp(-r/r_0).$$
As far as I know, in case of 1D linear array of atoms the normal modes are studied by writing the equation of motion with linearised inter-particle force and then Fourier transforming it with respect to space and time to obtain the dispersion relation.

My question is: how can I linearise the interparticle force if the particles are located in a circular lattice ? In the linear case, I obtain the spring constant, $K_x$ on linearising the interparticle force. How can I obtain the spring constant in the circular case ?